# Creating Flash Light with Voice Command JAVA Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, voice, flashlight

I'm a total noob android studio, I've been doing a little project with the flashLight and with the switch button and create a voice button and say " turn on the flash light " then the light will turn on, same thing as turn it off, I already create the flash light button to turn it on and off, but I do not know how to add the command method to it, I did create the google command, but it doesn't work Please help. Thank You.

```
// this is the code I did for the flash light, I create an on/ off switch and the text will change when the light is on or off. 

{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                torch(isChecked);

            }
        });
    }



    private void torch(boolean isChecked) {

        try {
            cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
            cameraID = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraID,isChecked);
            result = isChecked? "ON" : "OFF";
            textView.setText(result);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

I did try the speech recognizer and google command but still doesn't work.

Please help me. Thank you.